# Ruby : Wrap Double Quotes With Single Quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've searched everywhere in SO and no lucks. Basically, i have this kind of array :

`["a", "b", "c"]`

I need to wrap this double quotes with single quotes to be like this :

`['"a"', '"b"', '"c"']`

The main reason for why i need to wrap this array element is because i need to query jsonb object in my database (PostgreSQL). The sample of query is like this :

`data -> '#{af.column}' @> any(array#{@arr}::jsonb[])`

To query jsonb object i need to put single quotes for each element.

**UPDATE**

Why i need to do this ? Its because, i need to combine multiple query into an array. Below is my example codes :

```
    @conditions = args[:conditions] unless !args[:conditions].present?
    @tables = ["assigned_contact"]
    @query = self.joins({:assigned_contact => :call_campaign_answers})
      .where(@conditions.join(" AND "))
      .where("(data->>'age')::int between ? and ?", args[:min_age].to_i, args[:max_age].to_i)
      .where("data -> 'gender' @> any(array[?]::jsonb[])", args[:gender].map(&:to_json))
      .where("call_campaign_answers.answer IN (?)", args[:answers]).size
```

Where args[:conditions] are my query that i need to do wrape double quotes in single quotes.

If theres any other simple / method available, please let me know.

Comment: Can you show how you're inserting this in the database and why you'd need to do manual escaping? Using string interpolation is **extremely dangerous** and needs to be avoided.

Comment: @tadman , i've updated my question. Its compulsory for me to achieve this query result with multiple query in array. If theres any other way please suggest.

Comment: @tadman what do you mean by "string interpolation is extremely dangerous"? How so? Is this only relevant with a DB value?

Comment: @Jake It's relevant whenever there's contextual escaping necessary (e.g. JavaScript, HTML, JSON or SQL, among others). You must escape correctly, and the "slap quotes on either side and hope for the best" method is not the correct way. In most cases the danger comes from what someone malicious might do with this. If you have a SQL hole you're open to all kinds of problems, including having your database stolen, remote code injection, or worse. A JavaScript hole can lead to script injection, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

```
ary = %w[a b c]
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Then

```
new_ary = ary.map {|el| %Q["#{el}"] }
```

produces exactly your desired output:

```
new_ary == ['"a"', '"b"', '"c"']
#=> true
```

Comment: This adds quotes, but it completely ignores JSON escaping concerns. This should be `map { |el| JSON.dump(el) }` or `el.to_json` if available. If any of those values contains quotes this will fail. If any of those values contain characters with special meaning within a JSON string this will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is you're not returning a single JSON array, but multiple independent arrays which could be a syntax error. Use a singular JSON value:

```
.where("data -> 'gender' @> any(array[?]::jsonb[])", args[:gender].to_json)
```